# Create a table in Hive and populate it with data

Tags: hive

While trying to load data in a Hive table I encountered a behavior that looks strange to me. My data is made up of JSON objects loaded as records in a table called twitter_test containing a single column named "json".

Now I want to extract three fields from each JSON and build a new table called "my_twitter". I thus issue the command

```
CREATE TABLE my_twitter AS SELECT regexp_replace(get_json_object(t.json, '$.body\[0]'), '\n', '') as text, get_json_object(t.json, '$.publishingdate\[0]') as created_at, get_json_object(t.json, '$.author_screen_name\[0]') as author from twitter_test AS t;
```

The result is a table with three columns that contains no data. However, if I run the `SELECT` command alone it returns data as expected.

By trial and error I found out that i need to add `LIMIT x` at the end of the query for data to be inserted in the new table. The question is: why?
Furthermore, seems strange that I need to know in advance the number `x` of rows returned by the `SELECT` statement for the `CREATE` to work correctly. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a table on this json data using the JSON serde which would parse the json objects and then you could easily select each individual columns easily.

Find below a sample hive DDL for creating a json table using json serde

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `json_table`(
  A string
  ,B string
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'PATH'
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I'll give it a try for sure. However the problem is more general. Consider the following query:
`INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE my_twitter SELECT "this" as text, "is" as created_at, "dummy" as author FROM twitter_test LIMIT 1;`
It does not work if I remove `LIMIT 1` at the end.